# Capturing the Return Value of a JavaScript Iterator

Tags: javascript, iterator

Consider the following iterator. It yields strings 'foo' and 'bar' and then returns 'quux' as a return value. I can use `Array.from` to extract the yields from the iterator but if I do this, I have no way of reading out the return value. The return value is no longer returned by the iterator since `Array.from` already received (and discarded?) it as part of the protocol.

```js
const iterator = (function* () {
  yield 'foo'
  yield 'bar'
  return 'quux'
})()
const [foo, bar] = Array.from(iterator)
const quux = // ???
```

The only solution I can think of is writing a spy procedure that monitors the iteration and stores the return value into a predefined variable as a side effect before `Array.from` discards the return value. Are there better alternative ways of accessing the return value?

```js
let quux
const spy = function* (i) { /* extract return value from i and store it to quux */ }
const [foo, bar] = Array.from(spy(iterator))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right - when the iterator `next` function returns `{ done: true, value: 'whatever' }` the value is silently discarded.

As you already said, you could write a wrapper function (or a class, if you wanted to). But instead of saving it to an external variable, you could make it convert this last value to a regular iterated value.

For example:

```js
function* yieldFinal (iterator) {
  let done, value
  do {
    ({ done, value } = iterator.next())
    yield value
  } while (!done)
}

const iterator = (function* () {
  yield 'foo'
  yield 'bar'
  return 'quux'
})()

const [foo, bar, quux] = Array.from(yieldFinal(iterator))

console.log(foo, bar, quux)
```

(Note: If there was no explicit return value, then you'd get `undefined` for the last value.)

But, then the question is, why do you even need to go to these lengths? Instead of writing `return 'quux'` you could write `yield 'quux'; return` and achieve the same thing without going through all the hoops...

Comment: In TypeScript it makes a difference since `Generator<number, number, never>` is guaranteed to always contain at least one number where as `Generator<number, void, never>` might not contain any values.

Comment: Here is my code in case you are interested. It is a bit of a mess but it does the job. CherryDT's solution was pretty close to what I was already doing. https://github.com/maasglobal/scrapql/blob/master/src/utils/non-empty-list.ts

Answer (score -1):

Another solution:

```
function extractIterator<TItem, TResult>(iter: Generator<TItem, TResult>) {
    const items: TItem[] = [];
    let result: IteratorResult<TItem, TResult>;
    while ((result = iter.next())) {
        if (result.done) {
            return {
                items,
                result: result.value,
            };
        }
        items.push(result.value);
    }
    throw 'unreachable';
}
```